# Code optimization: Reduce method calling by storing return value

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization

I have created a method in c# which is fairly simple BUT i use it everywhere on a page. is there a way to reduce method calling, i mean once method called, the return value stored somewhere and i use that value instead. here is my code.

I have declared some public properties like this.

```
public OrderCollection GetAllClickCollectOrders
{
    get
    {
        return GetClickCollectOrderDetails(Session["SelectedStorePostCode"].ToString());
    }
}

public OrderCollection GetShippedClickCollectOrders
{
    get
    {
        return GetShippedClickCollectOrderDetails();
    }
}
```

AND here are the methods..

```
protected OrderCollection GetClickCollectOrderDetails(string postcode)
{
    // some database ziggy wiggy...

    return cncOrderCol;
}

protected OrderCollection GetShippedClickCollectOrderDetails()
{
    // some database ziggy wiggy...

    return cncShippedOrderCol;
}
```

So, lets say whn i want the collection i am calling it this way.

```
BindGridView(GetAllClickCollectOrders);
orderCount.Text = "Total orders placed: " + GetAllClickCollectOrders.Count;

if (isShipped.Checked)
{
    BindGridView(GetShippedClickCollectOrders);
    orderCount.Text = "Total orders shipped: " + GetShippedClickCollectOrders.Count;
}
```

---

So whenever i use the property, it calls the methods everytime and goes to database and returns me the result. however, most of the time results are the same unless i change the `Session["SelectedStorePostCode"]` value. I was thinking if there are any better ways for storing that results somewhere and use that.

Note: The code works fine but i am looking for better performance. Thanks guys...

Comment: y not first check that there is change in Session["SelectedStorePostCode"] value or not..then call the function..

Comment: What have you tried? Have you thought about a simple cache? Why does it not work for you?

Comment: i have not thought of cache at all. BUT i think it will make the page more heavy as i am not sure how much records the return collection has. it could be 1, 100, 1000..

Answer (score 1):

[`System.Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dd642331%28v=VS.110,d=hv.2%29.aspx) should be what you're looking for.

```
public OrderCollection GetAllClickCollectOrders {
  get {
    return m_allClickCollectOrders.Value;
  }
}
private Lazy<OrderCollection> m_allClickCollectOrders = new Lazy<OrderCollection>(
  () => GetClickCollectOrderDetails(Session["SelectedStorePostCode"].ToString()));
```

Of course, this assumes that the value never changes after being initialized. If it can change, other answers may be better suited.

Comment: it would be more useful if you can give some example of using this related to my question...

Comment: I've extended my answer. I hope it's more helpful now.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to want is to cache the results of your database calls.

You can achieve that by storing the results from the database in an instance of the [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) class.

A `Cache` item can be set to expire after a certain amount of time, so you can be certain that the value will update every so often, if the underlying data has changed.

This is suitable for items that are shared between all users (sessions) - if you wish to cache items that are unique between users, you can store the values in session variables, though this can cause memory pressures on your web server.

Answer (score 1):

something like?

```
private string collectOrders = String.Empty;

public OrderCollection GetAllClickCollectOrders
{
    get
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(collectOrders)
             collectOrders = GetClickCollectOrderDetails(Session["SelectedStorePostCode"].ToString());
        return collectOrders;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the value as a `Session` variable;

```
public OrderCollection GetAllClickCollectOrders
{
    get
    {
        if(Session["OrderCollection"] == null)
        {
            Session["OrderCollection"] = GetClickCollectOrderDetails(Session["SelectedStorePostCode"].ToString());
         return Session["OrderCollection"] as OrderCollection;
    }
}
```

One drawback of this approach is that you will not be able know if there are any changes in the database. If value does not change, no problem; otherwise you will need to implement a proper cache mechanism to remove the related session variable when db changes.

Comment: i think you are right... if the value does not change then your code might works, BUT what if the value changes and then i need to compare the Session...

Comment: as a simple workaround, you may clear the related session variable when changing OrderCollection.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you have something like:

```
private OrderCollection AllClickCollectOrders;

public OrderCollection GetAllClickCollectOrders
{
    get
    {
        if(AllClickCollectOrders == null)
        {
           AllClickCollectOrders = GetClickCollectOrderDetails(Session["SelectedStorePostCode"].ToString());
        }
        return AllClickCollectOrders;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:

```
OrderCollection _GetAllClickCollectOrders = null;
bool goToDB = false;
public OrderCollection GetAllClickCollectOrders
{
    get
    {
         if(_GetAllClickCollectOrders == null || goToDB)
        _GetAllClickCollectOrders = GetClickCollectOrderDetails(Session["SelectedStorePostCode"].ToString());

         return _GetAllClickCollectOrders;

    }
}
```